# Logarithms and Arctanh - A proof

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

I'm struggling with a part of a proof that I have to make, I need to show that $ f_1 = 4 x^4 \tanh ^{-1}(\sqrt{1-4x^2})$ is equal to $ f_2 = x^{4}  \ln \left[\frac{4 x^{4}}{\left(1-\sqrt{1-4 x^{2}}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{1-4 x^{2}}+\left(\sqrt{1-4 x^{2}}-3\right) x^{2}\right)}\right] $. My issue is that plotting the function with Mathematica they seem different but if I do few substitution I can prove that they are analytically the same and I can't seem to find a mistake in neither of the two.

The analytical derivation goes like this:

We know that we can write the Arctanh as

\begin{equation}
\tanh ^{-1}(x) =\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)
\end{equation}
therefore I can solve this equation for $y$

\begin{equation}
\frac{4 x^4}{\left(1-\sqrt{1-4 x^2}\right) \left(\left(\sqrt{1-4 x^2}-3\right) x^2-\sqrt{1-4 x^2}+1\right)} \equiv \frac{y+1}{1-y}
\end{equation}
and I find the substitution

\begin{equation}
y  \rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}{1-2 x^2}
\end{equation}
therefore I can re-write $f_2$ like

\begin{equation}
f_2 = 2 x^4 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}{1-2 x^2}\right)
\end{equation}
and then I can prove that

\begin{equation}
2 x^4 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}{1-2 x^2}\right)-4 x^4 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-4 x^2}\right) \equiv 0
\end{equation}
so they are equal. Is there any mistake here? Or is Mathematica having trouble with plotting the log?

Comment: Maybe you can check that they have same derivatives, so that they are equals up to an additive constant, and then check that the constant is zero by replacing for some $x$.

Comment: When I plot $f_1$ and $f_2$ with Maple, they come out the same.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks, that is very helpful! I think then there should be some typo on my code (the actual functions are more involved) or a problem with Mathematica